# ExpressJS Proxy Resulting in 503

Tags: express, proxy, vuejs3

I've built a simple proxy to interact with my API. However I am getting 503 errors when using it. My proxy is built as below

```javascript
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();

app.use('^/proxyThis', createProxyMiddleware({target: 'https://my-api.com/aspect/of/api'}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'));
});
app.use(express.static('dist'))

https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("server.cert"),
    },
    app
).listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(
        "Listening on port 3000! Go to https://localhost:3000/"
    );
});
```

However whenever I pass my URLs to the proxy like this:

```javascript
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      customerID: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveID(event) {
      this.customerID = event.target.value;
    },
    checkID() {
      let res = fetch(`/proxyThis?itemsPerPage=10&valueToCheck=${this.customerID}`);
      try {
          console.log('Success: ', res);
      } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error: ', error);
      }
    },
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

If I go directly to the endpoint, it works fine, which leads me to believe it is my proxy setup, but I don't see where I am going wrong. I am using Vue 3, and interacting with the code like this:

```html
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
          <img alt="Site logo" class="logo" src="assets/logo.svg" width="333" height="187" />
        </header>
        <h1 class="app-title">Customer Check</h1>
        <input @input="saveID" placeholder="Customer ID" />
        <button @click="checkID">Check Customer ID</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.9/dist/vue.global.js" defer></script>
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
  </body>
```

I have tried various permutations of the code, and a few articles and suggestions from Google and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your current proxy setup forwards the entire path as it is. If your API expects the path to be modified (e.g., removing "/proxyThis" from the path before sending it to the API server), you'll need to add a pathRewrite option to your createProxyMiddleware configuration:

```
app.use('/proxyThis', createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'https://my-api.com/aspect/of/api', 
  pathRewrite: {'^/proxyThis' : ''}, // Remove '/proxyThis' from the path 
}));
```

OR OR OR, MAYBE

Enhanced Logging:
Augment your `console.log(req.body)` statement to include more request details like `req.method` and `req.url`. This will give you a clearer picture of what's being sent to the proxy and how it might be getting modified.

AND MOST IMPORTANT
Consider adding error handling within your proxy middleware to catch and log errors from the target API.

Comment: I added the pathRewrite but it still 503s. I was also under the impression we could shorthand the `createProxyMiddleware` line to this `app.use('^/proxyThis', createProxyMiddleware({target: 'https://my-api.com/aspect/of/api'}));`, which automatically incorporated the removal of `^/proxyThis`.

Comment: So I re-wrote the script slightly to incorporate the `console.log` you mentioned, and I get the following `[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> https://my-api.com/aspect/of/api
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/proxyThis" ~> ""
Req.Method:  GET
Req.Url:  /itemsPerPage=10&valueToCheck=1234567890`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).